# How to sort the column of a 2d vector?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

each column needs to be sorted, for example for this input:

```
3 //3 by 3 matrix

2 3 4
34 3 1
4 54 2
```

the output should be

```
2 3 1
4 3 2 
34 54 4
```

this is my code yet:

```
    cin >> n;

    vector<vector<int>> A(n, vector<int>(n));

    for (auto &row : A)
        for (auto &el : row)
            cin >> el;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sort(A.begin(), A.end(), [&](vector<int>& l, vector<int>& j) {
            return (l[i] < j[i]); 
            });

    for (auto row : A)
    {
        for (auto el : row)
            cout << el << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
```

the problem with my code is that it sorts some columns but not all. Please help me to fix it

if i put in the imput the first example above, my out put is :

```
34 3 1
4 54 2
2 3 4
```

only the last column get sorted

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You are making things harder than necessary for yourself. a `vector<vector<int>>` is an array of array. It doesn't care what the higher-level meaning of it is. If you had a vector of columns instead of a vector of rows, it would be a lot easier.

Comment: @Frank please explain by showing an example

Comment: @MogovanJonathan -- The problem is that each iteration of that loop messes up the previous sorted column.  At the very least, you should have seen that and mentioned it in your post, or noticed it and come up with another design..  You have to change your representation of what a `vector<vector<int>>` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that for each iteration of the `for` loop, the `std::sort` can potentially change the already sorted column.

For example, if you sort column `i`, then columns `i-1`, `i-2`, etc. can lose the changes that were made to sort those columns.

Without changing too much of your original code, and albeit not the most efficient way to do this, you could create an auxiliary `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` and save the sorted column results of each iteration inside the loop in the auxiliary vector.

When done with the loop, assign the auxiliary vector back to the original vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::vector<int>> A = {{2, 3, 4}, {34, 3, 1}, {4, 54, 2}};

int main()
{
    if ( !A.empty() && !A[0].empty() )
    {
        auto auxV = A; // The auxiliary vector<vector>

        for (size_t i = 0; i < A[0].size(); i++)
        {
            // Sort column i
            std::sort(A.begin(), A.end(), [&](vector<int>& l, vector<int>& j) {
                return (l[i] < j[i]); 
                });

            // Save the results of the sort of column i in the auxiliary vector  
            for (size_t j = 0; j < A.size(); ++j)
                auxV[j][i] = A[j][i];
        }
        A = auxV; // copy the results back to the original vector
   }

    // display results
    for (auto& row : A)
    {
        for (auto el : row)
            std::cout << el << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2 3 1 
4 3 2 
34 54 4
```