# sorting a 2d array by column in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I need to sort 2d array by columns.

```
10 20 5
15 13 43
0  14 1
```

I would like to transform the above array into this:

```
15 20 43
10 14 5
0  13 1
```

Comment: I recommend std::sort: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: We do not know in what form these "2D arrays" are in.  Is it `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`?  Is it `array[3][3];`?  Is it `int **` and then dynamically allocate the data?  This is why we need a [mcve] of what you are attempting, not just a general description.

Comment: If you use `std::sort`, you'll need to provide an iterator that can increment by column.  Otherwise, you'll need to write your own.  Also consider that the sort algorithm needs to swap items, in your case, it needs to swap rows.

Comment: [Is this what you are lookng for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61543723/how-to-sort-the-column-of-a-2d-vector)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that takes a 2D array of `int`s as a standard container `std::array<std::array<int>>` or `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` and sorts each column by making a temporary `std::vector<int>` of the column and using `std::sort` on it.

```cpp
template<typename ArrayType>
void sortAllColumns(ArrayType& array) {
    // go through each column
    const size_t columns = array[0].size();
    for (size_t column_index = 0; column_index < columns; ++column_index) {
        // create a vector from column
        std::vector<int> column;
        column.resize(array.size());
        // add elements to column vector
        for (size_t row_index = 0; row_index < array.size(); ++row_index) {
            column[row_index] = array[row_index][column_index];
        }
        // sort column
        std::sort(column.begin(), column.end(), [](const int lhs, const int rhs) {
            return lhs > rhs;
        });
        // update column in array
        for (size_t row_index = 0; row_index < array.size(); ++row_index) {
            array[row_index][column_index] = column[row_index];
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```cpp
template <typename ArrayType>
void coutArray(const ArrayType& array) {
    for (const auto& row : array) {
        for (const auto& element : row) {
            std::cout << element << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector array {
        std::vector{ 10, 20, 5 },
        std::vector{ 15, 13, 43 },
        std::vector{ 0, 14, 1 }
    };

    sortAllColumns(array);
    coutArray(array);
}
```

Produces:

```
15 20 43
10 14 5
0 13 1
```

Comment: Can you show this code actually work with the OP's data, to prove it actually does work?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have added an example that work's with OP's data.

Comment: I will now edit because I have sorted in the wrong direction

Comment: I have now realised they want ALL columns sorted, not by row but by value. Let me redo my answer